# (Apple Silicon+UTM) aarch64 image-based VM deployment

Tags: fedora, apple

I'm running my aarch64-Fedora server in UTM on an M1 Mac via the Apple hypervisor by using aarch64 as the QEMU architecture option in UTM.

I know that for SD cards, these images can simply be dd'd to the device, and then enlarged later, but what is the recommended procedure in my case?

So far, I know I can extract the .raw disk image and run it right away in UTM, but I'd like to use the qcow2 format for the VM disk, and a larger disk size than simply 'whatever the image extracts to.'

Can I create the .qcow2 disk image with UTM at a larger size, say, 40GB and then dd the Fedora image to the .qcow2 file like '`dd if=fedoraimage.raw of=/directory/place/virtualmachineimage.qcow2`' from the command line within Big Sur, or is there something I'm missing, here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use `dd` to convert a raw image file to a .qcow2 file.

Instead, you use `qemu-img` (from the `qemu-utils` package) to convert it.   e.g.

```
qemu-img convert -O qcow2 fedoraimage.raw /directory/place/virtualmachineimage.qcow2
```

There are various options for controlling exactly how the .qcow2 file is created.  e.g.
you can compress the .qcow2 image file with the `-c` option, and you can also optionally show a progress bar during the conversion with the `-p` option.

---

Note: if the image file contains formatted partitions, in order to resize them you'll need to:

- use `qemu-img resize` to grow the .qcow2
- edit the partition table to increase the size of a partition
- grow the filesyystem with, e.g., `resize2fs`

I'm not at all sure how you'd do the last two steps on a Mac, I can only guess.  On Linux, you'd use `qemu-nbd` to treat the .qcow2 as if it were a network block device.  On a Mac, you may have to boot the VM with a gparted ISO image or similar.

Comment: Hello, I found that the simplest way to achieve this was to boot a live image in the VM, and with both the raw image file and final VirtIO storage device (.qcow2) attached, to then dd the raw to the qcow image from the live environment. From there, Gparted would extend the logical volume with no issues.

Comment: @user69136 yep, that would work too....but it'll waste a lot of space (about as much space as there are unused sectors in the raw image).   There are methods for reclaiming that space (using either `qemu-img convert` again or `virt-sparsify` or discard & fstrim) on serverfault at [free up not used space on a qcow2-image-file on kvm/qemu](https://serverfault.com/questions/329287/free-up-not-used-space-on-a-qcow2-image-file-on-kvm-qemu)